# Mini server implementation in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fileshare

I'm trying to implement a little server service in order to upload files via web browser to my iOS app. An example of this feature is implemented in the following app:

http://itunes.apple.com/uy/app/files-document-reader/id294150896?mt=8

seems to be very simple, but don't know where to start.
I've been also looking for clues or some sample codes about this kind of implementation with no success, but maybe just don't know how to google the problem correctly.

Any clues, guides, links, etc...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to transfer a video using aws sdk , video can be more than 1 GB , i think i cant do it with background service in ios , is it possible for me to do it using this type of server ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://myutil.com/2009/6/15/simple-way-to-embed-a-http-server-into-your-iphone-app) is a wrapper to embed the moongoose http server in your iphone application. Another simple http server is [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html). The latter one is the one I used in my application, recently.

**EDIT:**

There's at least a [third](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) one, too.

Comment: I end up using the third option.. some bugs rised, not so easy to handle, but got a pretty stable version by now.. many thanks!

Comment: The third one... for mac, do you know how can I run this as a daemon without the gui and NSApplicationMain?