# How to play .ts (transport Stream) file locally in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, avplayer

I want to play .ts files which are stored in my local disk. I can play the .ts file using .m3u8 by streaming.

But i want to play these stored local ts files directly(with my AVPlayer) without streaming. I mean i want to play without using m3u8.

is it possible in iOS? If possible please explain how to achieve this?

Comment: If you register an account you'll be able to edit your posts and leave comments.

Answer (score 1):

If file:// URLs don't work, I guess you could run a minimal HTTP server inside your app and have that serve the files to AVPlayer.

Comment: Hi steven Kramer,  I can play ts in my iOS by streaming from server. But i have ts file stored locally like mp4 or mp3 in a directory. is it possible to play ts directly as mp4 plays by giving the file path.  And i'm using iOS Simulator to test this.

Comment: I understood that. I suggest you try to put these files in your resources, and then use a file URL to play them. Try something like `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"playlist.m3u8" withExtension: nil]` to get the URL. Pass that on to AVPlayer. Failing that, I think you'll have to embed a small HTTP server inside your app that will feed the data to AVPlayer, allowing you to use a normal HTTP url.

Comment: Hi Steven Kramer, Thanks for your reply, ya i followed your above said steps. 1. I used [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"List.m3u8" withExtension: nil] then i passed the fileURL to AVplayer, But it did not play. 2. I added mini [MongooseDaemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358493/mini-server-implementation-in-objective-c) HTTP server in my app to feed the data to AVplayer. Its launching my application and suddenly exiting without error or exception. So can you explain how to trace this.

Comment: @StevenKramer minimal HTTP server embedded, do you have any documents ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that, I didn't investigate any further.

Comment: How to create HTTP server inside my app that will feed the data to AVPlayer?